# c# return few values from method async task

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, .net-4.7.2

I get an error: CS1001  C# Identifier expected

```
static async Task<(bool, string)> TryGetHtml(string url)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
  {
    return (false, null);
  }
  string html = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(url);
  return (true, html);
}
```

P.S. Use (NET Framework 4.7.2)

Comment: But which language version are you using? Project properties - Build - Advanced (as this is a language feature, not framework)

Comment: @Mihail I checked your code . It is working fine

Comment: c# 6.0  https://dotnetfiddle.net/kAVGgH

Comment: Using c#7 feature with c#6 compiler not going to work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples

Comment: Alexei Levenkov Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Check your Output window...errors sometimes "hide" in there.